# Magento 2 : Custom Checkout Step Issue While Reload

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

Before reload the checkout page, the shipping-method step look like this.

[image]

After reload the checkout page, the shipping-method step look like this

[image]

anyone please help.

Comment: Any help @Dhiren Vasoya?

Comment: Have you check the consol when reload page? Any error on that?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: check magento log files?

Comment: Checked No errors in log files

Comment: It works fine for #payment. May be because payment was in core module.

Comment: @AveshNaik did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try - & php bin/magento se:up this command in your terminal. and check what value do you have in - web/js/view/%your_js_file% on this line - 
//add here your logic to display step,

isVisible: ko.observable(true),

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your custom created step is set to visible in your step navigate function:

```
navigate: function (step) {
    step && step.isVisible(true);
},
```